# AWS Systems Manager Session Manager Port Forwarding not connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, portforwarding, rdp

I have an EC2 Windows 2019 Server instance in a VPC in the private subnet. I have a bastion instance in the public subnet, and I know the bastion instance works, because it is being used for internet access for my Lambda API. I have VPC endpoints to:

- com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.ssm
- com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.ec2messages
- com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.ec2

I would like to connect with RDP to the EC2 instance to manage my MySQL RDS instance. I have been trying to get Systems Manager Session Manager Port Forwarding to work, following several guides.

I have tried every guide I could find, and everything seem correctly setup.

Is it required to have specific ports setup inbound / outbound on the bastion instance SG, or on the SG the EC2 I want to RDP to is in? I have not been able to see that anywhere.

I have run AWSSupport-TroubleshootRDP and everything pass with "Success" and from the output everything looks good.

When I run the port forwarding command on my machine it starts the session, but I never get "Connection accepted" and the RDP connection fails when I try that.

Can anyone point me to what else I can do to verify that I have the correct network configurations, and to test why I am not getting "Connection accepted", as I have seen I should be getting from the guides.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with regular `ssh`? Forget about SSM Session manager for a bit, and check if all works as intended when you use plain ssh port forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the ability to run RDP via Session Manager Port Forwarding, I did the following:

- Launched an Amazon EC2 instance running Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Base
- Associated an IAM Role with `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` permissions
- Set the Security Group to **no inbound connections** (to confirm that connections were being made via Session Manager)
- Confirmed that I could use Session Manager to connect to PowerShell on the instance (using the Session Manager console)
- Ran the following command on my Mac:

```
aws ssm start-session --target i-xxx --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession --parameters '{"portNumber":["3389"],"localPortNumber":["3389"]}'
```

- Used **Microsoft Remote Desktop** (which connects via RDP) to connect to `localhost`
- It prompted me for a password. I used **Get Windows Password** to decode and obtain the password.
- It **connected successfully**

So, yes, you can use Session Manager Port Forwarding to establish an RDP connection with a Windows instance even if it is in a private subnet (which I simulated by removing all inbound rules on the security group).

If you are having further problems, it might be due to your VPC Endpoint configurations.

Comment: See also: [Instance Administration using AWS SSM Port Forwarding](https://medium.com/@machinate/instance-administration-using-aws-ssm-port-forwarding-cd82bcb30107)

Comment: Thank you John. I had done all of this, but I decided to try again to confirm the same way you did. I had removed the VPC Endpoints, and I did not recreate them. I am pretty sure my problem was I was using the Microsoft remote desktop app from the Microsoft store, because it was in the example from AWS. When I used the standard remote dekstop application and connected as Administrator it worked.